# How to avoid being "stringly" typed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I've been doing a course about clean code. The course states that being "stringly" typed is a bad thing to readability and recommends using a different structure(The course uses C#):

```
//Dirty
if (employeeType == "manager") 

//Clean
if (employee.Type == EmployeeType.Manager)
```

My question is: How can I implement a structure like that in javascript?

Should I create an object like this one?

```
EmployeeType = {
    Manager: "manager"
}

employee = {
    Type: : "manager"
}
```

Is this the better way to do it?

Comment: js is loose typing, you should use `employeeType === "manager"` instead of `employeeType == "manager"` (REF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Comment: for js loose typing, take a look at this one: http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/03/understanding-loose-typing-in.html

Comment: not sure how "loose typing" is at all relevant!

Answer (score 2):

If you use ES6 and classes, you can use `instanceof`.

```
class Animal {
    greet() {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  greet() {
    console.log("Woof!");
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
  greet() {
    console.log("Meow!");
  }
}

let dog = new Dog();

console.log(dog instanceof Animal); // Returns true
console.log(dog instanceof Dog); // Returns true
console.log(dog instanceof Cat); // Returns false
console.log(dog instanceof Object); // Caveat: returns true!
```

Or in ES5:

```
function Animal() {
}

Animal.prototype.greet = function() {
  // Do nothing
}

function Dog() {
  Animal.call(this);
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

Dog.prototype.greet = function() {
  console.log("Woof!");
}

function Cat() {
  Animal.call(this);
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

Cat.prototype.greet = function() {
  console.log("Meow!");
}

var dog = new Dog();

console.log(dog instanceof Animal); // Returns true
console.log(dog instanceof Dog); // Returns true
console.log(dog instanceof Cat); // Returns false
console.log(dog instanceof Object); // Caveat: returns true!
```

Note: `instanceof` is not an ES6 feature, but classes are. You can use `instanceof` with ES5-style prototypes. For more info, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)

Comment: Wouldn't the ES5 equivalent involve creating the `greet()` methods on the `.prorotype` rather than directly on each instance? In any case, this doesn't answer the question, which asked how to tell whether an employee is a manager or not, because the OO way to represent that would be instances of `Employee` with a `type` property, or to have a `Manager` that inherits from `Employee`.

Comment: @nnnnnn You're right on the ES5 prototype; I have updated that. Didn't see the need to involve inheritance (was just thinking about showing how the OP can use `instanceof` instead of "stringly" types), but have updated the answer to include that so it's more analogous to the question.